# Can you identify these curved bricks for me?

Tags: part-identification

[image: curved bricks]

(I don't care about the decal, I just need the general shape)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Large one is [Brick, Round Corner 10 x 10 with Slope 33 Edge, Axle Hole, Facet Cutout with Holographic Circuit Pattern Model Right (Sticker)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58846pb08R#T=C&C=11)

[image]

which is a decorated version of [Brick, Round Corner 10 x 10 with Slope 33 Edge, Axle Hole, Facet Cutout](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58846)

Smaller ones are [Brick, Round Corner 4 x 4 Macaroni Wide with 3 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48092#T=C)

[image]

Comment: Out of interest, what is the significance of "macaroni"? (Apologies if this is a newb question)

Comment: @IanF1 It's shaped like a piece of elbow macaroni.

Comment: @IanF1 for some people this piece just looks like a piece of pasta/macaroni. There's also smaller macaroni round brick, 2 x 2 in size. As well as a tile to cover studs on both size macaroni bricks.

Answer (score 5):

The big one looks like [58846](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58846&name=Brick,%20Round%20Corner%2010%20x%2010%20with%20Slope%2033%20Edge,%20Axle%20Hole,%20Facet%20Cutout&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=C) Brick, Round Corner 10 x 10 with Slope 33 Edge, Axle Hole, Facet Cutout

The others look like [48092](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48092&name=Brick,%20Round%20Corner%204%20x%204%20Macaroni%20Wide%20with%203%20Studs&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=C) Brick, Round Corner 4 x 4 Macaroni Wide with 3 Studs

Answer (score 3):

There are three 
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48092&name=Brick,%20Round%20Corner%204%20x%204%20Macaroni%20Wide%20with%203%20Studs&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=C

And as Dan said, the larger one is
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=58846&name=Brick,%20Round%20Corner%2010%20x%2010%20with%20Slope%2033%20Edge,%20Axle%20Hole,%20Facet%20Cutout&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=C